# How to avoid ghost collisions in box2dweb

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, box2d, box2dweb

I'm using box2dweb to create a game, but want to have an uneven ground in my game. However, box2dweb isn't up to date and doesn't contain edge chains to fix ghost collisions yet.

Currently, my ground looks like this: http://gyazo.com/db00ef9f6bda6bfc48fd733509af8b1c.png

It is comprised of b2polygon edges, but there are still ghost collisions at the points where the edges meet. Is there any other way to prevent the ghost collisions without clipping off corners on rectangles or changing my shapes into circles?